# is RapidSSL wildcard cert supported by major browsers?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I'm thinking of buying a wildcard SSL cert from clickSSL :

http://www.clickssl.com/rapidssl/rapidsslwildcard.aspx

That would be a rapidssl certificate, and I was looking into my firefox options to see if RapidSSL is in the list of recognized Authorities. My certificate manager doesn't mention RapidSSL anywhere.

Am I looking for the wrong name, e.g. is rapidssl recognized by browsers under a different name? I want to be sure that this certificate is working in all major browsers (including IE6)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at AlphaSSL for a budget certificate, as the Rapid/Verisign brands have mis-issued certificates in the past, go over to prontossl and let them know you have come from this site, and they'll give you extra discount as well

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could find a site that uses a RapidSSL certificate, but according to what I read they are under the "Equifax Secure CA" certificate root. That one seems to be in all the clients I use.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have their own root certificate. It is a GeoTrust/VeriSign brand. But they are supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

We have bought RapidSSL WildCard Certificate from platinum authority of RapidSSL Certificates a RapidSSLonline. We have inquired from them about RapidSSL WildCard Web Browsers and Mobile Devices compatibility and they have stated all the details clearly that RapidSSL WildCard is being completely supported by all latest web browsers and smart phone devices.

Here are the list of latest web browsers which they had mentioned us, IE 5.01+, AOL 5+, Netscape 4.7+, Opera 7+, Safari, Mozilla 1+, Firefox 1+.